# How to free memory for Queue? Mine doesn't free

Tags: c++, queue, free

This is the revised version.

It takes 3.5GB memory and the pop function doesn't free the memory... How can I use new and delete to get those memory back? Now I'm using STL. since new and delete only works for pointers?

```
queue<Graphnode> ss;
    for(i=0;i<30000000;i++)
    {
        ss.push( *g.root);
    }

    printf("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\n");
        for(i=0;i<30000000;i++)
    {
        ss.pop();
    }
    printf("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\n");
    //delete &ss;
```

here is my node.h file. I think I need to malloc and free or New, delete pointers here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <tr1/array>

typedef struct point
{
    std::tr1::array<int, 16> state;
    int x;
}point;
typedef struct Graphnode
{
    struct point pvalue;
    int depth;
    struct Graphnode *up;
    struct Graphnode *down;
    struct Graphnode *left;
    struct Graphnode *right;
}Graphnode;
```

so after revise the code should look like this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <tr1/array>

typedef struct point
{
    std::tr1::array<int, 16> state;
    int x;
    int depth;
}point;
typedef struct Graphnode
{
    point *pvalue = (point *)malloc(sizeof(point));
    Graphnode *up = (Graphnode*)malloc(sizeof(Graphnode));
    Graphnode *down= (Graphnode*)malloc(sizeof(Graphnode));;
    Graphnode *left= (Graphnode*)malloc(sizeof(Graphnode));;
    Graphnode *right= (Graphnode*)malloc(sizeof(Graphnode));;
}Graphnode;
```

Comment: You should probably add the code for your `push` function, and how your are creating the elements of the queue.  You tagged your question `c++` but you are attempting to use `free`.

Comment: sorry..it is for queue not for stack. I changed that. I wonder what's the function in C++ like free() in C?

Comment: There is the `delete` operator.  See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new/operator%20delete/.  You should use `delete` iff you allocate objects with `new`. Also, in the c++ standard library by convention you use `push_front()` or `push_back()` to add elements to the head and tail of a container, hence the naming.

Comment: I should have said "ordered container", obviously that wouldn't apply to a `set` or associative container.

Comment: Okay, it is clear from your edit that this is pure C and not C++.  If you want to use C++, maybe read this first: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/containers.html.  If you are not implementing this as an exercise, I urge you to ditch all your code and use the standard library version of `queue`.

Comment: Always use `delete` with `new` and `free` with `malloc`. Do not mix them up.

Comment: Without actually looking at your code, just because you `free`d memory, doesn't mean your program is going to immediately use less memory.  It probably still belongs to your process, in case you need more again later.

Comment: Thank every body!! I'm coding an very descent research project. I've revised all my code to STL. now i have revised my code. But I found that the pop() function doesn't free memory as I expected. The memory stays the same. I wonder How can I use new and delete to get that memory back?

Comment: Nothing stops you to use free() in C++. The thing is that if you malloc() to allocate memory then you need to free(). This is old C-style. In C++, they have the 'new' operator to allocate memory and the 'delete' is the corresponding operator to release memory allocated using the 'new' operator. I see that all your above code is C-style so what you are using is OK. I fail to see any issues with the code you have pasted. Your code could have been better had you used your ifEmpty() in your enqueue() and dequeue() functions instead of making those NULL checks.

Comment: Try changing it to `queue<Graphnode*> ss;` and `ss.push(g.root);` and see what your memory usage shows.

Comment: I've revised my question thank you guys very very very much!

Comment: I've posted my node.h file as well. I wonder if the way i'm doing is right?

Comment: Can't initialize `Graphnode` in the `typedef` like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using `c++`, you should use `queue<T>` from the standard library.  Here is a reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/queue/.

For c++ code you should never write your own container classes unless it is absolutely necessary.  The standard library provides many useful containers that cover most use cases.  They are heavily used and tested and have been for many years.

Comment: If you use std::deque as the underlying container, the memory keeps growing.

Comment: This does not answer the question

Answer (score 0):

Even an empty queue structure will still use memory. I am assuming you have defined queue as something like

```
struct queue
{
    queueElement* head;
    queueElement* tail;
};
```

So an empty queue will still require the memory to store the `head` and `tail` pointers even when they are both `NULL`.

How are you "measuring" the memory usage? Obviously `sizeof` is no good as it'll just be the constant size of the `struct queue`. So I assume you've got some other tool or code which is measuring it. But the code looks OK to me, and shuld be releasing the memory as you expect.

One bug you have is that the dequeue function never sets `tail`. But if `head` is NULL after setting it to `head->next`, then you also need to set `tail` to NULL. Don't think this would cause a memory leak, but definitely opens you up to a corruption or segfault if you enqueue after a dequeue empties the queue.

Comment: I'm using the System monitor to monitor it. I revised the code to show How I did that....Thank you for your help,....!!

Answer (score 0):

Your queue can clean up after itself if and only if `struct Graphnode` is self-contained and does not contain pointers to allocated memory.

```
void emptyQueue(struct queue *q) {
    queueElement *element, *nextElement;
    element = q->head;
    while(element) {
        nextElement = element->next;
        free(element);
        element = nextElement;
    }
    initQueue(q);
}
```

Note that since `initQueue` does not `malloc`, its counterpart function, `emptyQueue`, should not `free`. This allows you to create queues on the stack if you need to.

If your `struct Graphnode` has pointers to allocated memory, then you will need to do this by hand, and not in `emptyQueue`. Your code will look something like:

```
struct Graphnode node;
while(!isEmpty(q)) {
    node = front(q);
    /* Delete the stuff in `node` here. */
    dequeue(q);
}
```

---

Some comments on your C code...

In `enqueue` you have:

```
if (q->head == NULL) {
    //first element
    q->head = newElement;
    q->tail = newElement;
} else {
     //put it to the tail
     q->tail->next= newElement;
     q->tail = newElement;
}
```

Since you're doing `q->tail = newElement;` in both paths, move it out:

```
if (q->head == NULL) {
    //first element
    q->head = newElement;
} else {
    //put it at the tail
    q->tail->next= newElement;
}
q->tail = newElement;
```

Also, consistent indentation is a good habit to have. Your text editor should make this easy for you.

In `dequeue`:

```
if (q->head == NULL) {
    //empty queue
    return;
} else {
    element = q->head;
    q->head = q->head->next;
    free(element);
}
```

The `else` isn't needed, since the first part always `return`s.

```
if (q->head == NULL) {
    //empty queue
    return;
}
element = q->head;
q->head = q->head->next;
free(element);
```

Finally, in `ifEmpty`:

```
return (q->head == NULL ? 1:0);
```

C represents true as nonzero and false as 0. The result of the `==` operator is guaranteed to be like this, so there's no point forcing true to be `1`;

```
return q->head == NULL;
```

---

One final note: on some systems, the "memory used" read out by a program like `top` might not go down. This is because the system is keeping the pages of freed memory around for future use. It may release the physical memory, but the virtual memory addresses will be kept around as "available" for your program until termination.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great help!!! I've revised the code using STL. So I need to redo my Graphnode to have new and delete there?

Comment: First tell me why `point` in `Graphnode` is allocated from the heap. Why isn't it just stored right in `Graphnode`?